# Redirect Elastic Beanstalk IP to Domain through Nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using Elastic Beanstalk to serve a load balanced web application. Our domains are set up, which ends up giving us three possible ways to access our server (either HTTP/HTTPS):

1. `example.com`
2. `x.elasticbeanstalk.com`
3. `IP address`

Something like `dig example.com` would give you the possible IP addresses that could get you to the same server.

The issue we're running into is that our raw IP addresses are getting indexed by Google and we'd like to redirect the raw IP's to our `example.com` in Nginx. I have tried a few things, but none have really solved our problem. On a system like Elastic Beanstalk, hardcoding an IP address as a `server` in Nginx is a poor idea because the IP addresses can change so frequently.

This solution works well, though it only solves for the Elastic Beanstalk URLs and still ignores the IP addresses.

```
server {
    server_name .elasticbeanstalk.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

This solution handles every single case, but it breaks Elastic Beanstalk healthchecks for some reason. It seems like its breaking because Elastic Beanstalk healthcheck doesn't follow redirects, so it is expecting a `200` but getting a `301`. I guess I could redirect on every endpoint except `/healthcheck`, but that seems less than ideal.

```
if ($http_host != "example.com") {
    rewrite ^ https://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

So what we're looking for is some way to properly:

1. redirect an unknown IP address to a known domain through Nginx
2. maintain the functionality of Elastic Beanstalk healthcheck

Comment: "I guess I could redirect on every endpoint except `/healthcheck`, but that seems less than ideal." Why does that seem less than ideal? It sounds like a perfectly reasonable solution to me.

Comment: In my ideal world, no external client would ever be able to utilize that IP (they'd just be redirected to the main domain). So if it worked like that, except on one specific route, it just feels incomplete. It is the best option at this point though.

Comment: Are you not using a load balancer? If you blocked all traffic that isn't from the load balancer, using security groups, then the IP address wouldn't be usable anyway.

Comment: Oh no we are, but I think you're right. Our instances are on private subnets and the load balancer on public ones, but its probably some issue with the configuration there. This totally should be solvable from the security group, thanks for that.